# Why is my apollo-server-express instance hanging due to resolvers?

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I've recently wanted to get back into programming, and I know that Apollo GraphQL has moved to an asynchronous way to firing up the server per their documentation.

Since switching (and following docs), I can't get my server to fire up, and I don't know why.

When the server attempts to run, it hangs on the execution of `.start()` on my `ApolloServer` instance, even though I'm giving it (what I think) are both valid type definitions and resolvers.

The current iteration of my tiny boilerplate project is located [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-leakey-s48rt) on CodeSandbox.

When I run this code locally, I receive the following error (which isn't shown on CS?):

`Argument type {typeDefs: DocumentNode, resolvers: {Query: {hello(): string}}} is not assignable to parameter type ApolloServerExpressConfig`

This error is on line 9, where the instance of `ApolloServer` is created.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I was previously using `babel-plugin-import-graphql` but switched away from that to using a normal JS import w/ the `gql` tag just to be safe.   The problem appears to be with the resolver map, which doesn't make sense:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => "world!"
  }
};

export default resolvers;
```

Anyway, thanks in advance!  Would love to get this sorted out today.   I think if I don't, I'll end up just switching over to using Meteor for full-stack stuff and then use React for the front-end and just not worry about it anymore.

Comment: use docker? ... is it a whole/full error message? nothing more? ... sth TS related

Comment: I’m not using Docker.   That’s full message as copied from Webstorm.

Comment: it was suggestion to use docker ;) ... doesn't look like full error message ... config/versions problem? ...  try to define schema of ApolloServerExpressConfig type explicitely as in  https://geekyants.com/blog/full-stack-mern--graphql-boilerplate--starter-part-i-147

Comment: I can look into explicit typing, I wasn't using TS for any of this stuff, but I suppose I could also give that a try and see what happens later today.

Definitely something weird going on.